# Where does the factor of half come from, boltzmann distribution for bandgap energy

Tags: material-science, semiconductor-physics, probability

I have found that it is possible to calculate the conductivity of a semiconductor using the Boltzmann distribution:

The source is a slideshow presentation and doesn't list much information. The derivation given is as follows:
For an intrinsic semidconductor: $\sigma=n|e|\mu_e+p|e|\mu_h$

$\sigma \approx C_1n=C_1p =$

$\sigma \approx Ce^{-\frac{E_g}{2k_bT}}$   where C is a constant and $E_g$ the bandgap energy.

My question is: Where does the half in the exponent of the boltmann distibution come from?

Comment: "*I have found that...*" - Perhaps it would be a good idea to link the source.

Comment: From SRH theory assuming a mid-gap state for carrier generation/recombination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing more of what you did, but if the trap state is halfway between the conduction and valence bands, then it would have energy $E_t = \frac{E_g}{2}$.  The equilibrium fraction of the charge carriers in the trap state would then be given by
$$ n_t \propto e^{-\frac{E_t}{k_B T}} = e^{-\frac{E_g}{2k_B T}}$$

---

I think I somewhat misunderstood the question.  In intrinsic semiconductors, the carrier concentration goes like

$$ n_i \propto e^{-\frac{E_g - E_f}{k_B T}}$$
where $E_f$ is the Fermi energy.  In many semiconductors, $E_f$ is precisely in the middle of the band gap, so $E_g-E_f=E_g/2$.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the formula is based on trap-assisted generation/recombination. In this model the energy needed to generate a hole- electron pair is half of the bandgap energy, and that is why we fill in half of the bandgap energy in the boltzmann distribution.

Comment: @Zephron - correct. See Shockley-Reid-Hall. No mid-gap states and the density of carriers is much lower.

Comment: @Zephron I think I slightly misunderstood your question - my answer has been edited.